# How to create this route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have the following route:

```
resources :articles, except: [:index] do
   collection do
      get 'author/:id/articles' => 'articles#index', as: 'index_articles'
   end
end
```

This results in:

```
GET    /api/v1/articles/:id/author/:id/articles(.:format)
```

How can I turn this into the following?:

```
GET    /api/v1/author/:id/articles(.:format)
```

Comment: if you will write this `get 'author/:id/articles' => 'articles#index', as: 'index_articles'` outside `resources :articles` you will get desired route.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, would you add this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :articles, except: [:index]
resources :authors, path: "author", only: [] do
   resources :articles, only: :index, on: :member #-> url.com/author/:id/articles
end
```

Comment: Thanks, is there an advantage to using `member` instead of the other solution. Or is this just convention?

Comment: Just convention, it's also [extensible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility). Far better to scope around resources than using a solitary route, in case you wish to add extra routes afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Write this

```
get 'author/:id/articles' => 'articles#index', as: 'index_articles'
```

Outside the `resources :articles` block.